# Sweet alert 2 in a chrome extension not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I need some help with a chrome extension for pipefy that I'm developing. I'm totally stucked in the part where you click the button and it should open a sweet alert. Would you mind taking a look at my code? Thank you very much.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', carrega_ini);

function carrega_ini() {


    console.log('0:carregando');

    var botao = document.querySelector('.home button');
    if (botao) { botao.addEventListener('click', ativa_desativa) };
}


function ativa_desativa() {

    var botao = document.querySelector('.home button');
    if (!botao.className.includes('ativo')) {
    botao.className += ' ativo'; botao.innerText = 'Ligado';
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            code: '(' + leitura_botoes + ')();' //argument here is a string but function.toString() returns function's code
        }, (results) => {
            //Here we have just the innerHTML and not DOM structure
            console.log('Popup script:')
            console.log(results[0]);
        });

    }
    else { botao.className = botao.className.replace(/ativo/g, ''); botao.innerText = 'Desligado'; }
}

function leitura_botoes() {
    var el = document.querySelectorAll('.pp-card');

    var intervalo = '';

    console.log('mensagem do alem:' + el.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        el[i].addEventListener('click', funcao);


    }



    function funcao() {
        intervalo = setInterval(funcao2, 300);
    }

    function funcao2() {
        var el2 = document.querySelector('.pp-open-card');
        if (el2) {

            alert("funciounou2:" + intervalo);


            var contencao = document.getElementById('phase-3018555');

            if (!contencao) {
                clearInterval(intervalo);

                return;
            }

            var novoBotao = document.createElement('button');
            novoBotao.id = "new-botao";
            novoBotao.innerText = 'Ajustar Horas';
            contencao.appendChild(novoBotao);
            novoBotao.addEventListener("click", modificar_horas);
            clearInterval(intervalo);

        }
    }



    function modificar_horas() {
        swal({
            title: "Informe o tempo a ser ajustado",
            button: "Registrar",
            content: conteudo
        });



        var btn_ok = document.querySelector('.swal-button--confirm');
        btn_ok.addEventListener('click', function () {


            var inputTexto = document.getElementById('msg');
            var mensagem = inputTexto.value;
            if (mensagem.length > 0) {
                swal({
                    icon: "success",
                })
            }
            else {
                swal({
                    title: "Ops, você esqueceu algo!",
                    button: "Registrar",
                    content: conteudo
                })


            }
        })
    }



}
```

Comment: Is your `modificar_horas` function being called at all? Do you see this alert?  swal({
            title: "Informe o tempo a ser ajustado",
            button: "Registrar",
            content: conteudo
        });

Comment: oh no, i forgot to call the function modificar_horas? I dont know how to do it sorry im just learning how to program now :(

Comment: You have code to call it here: ` novoBotao.addEventListener("click", modificar_horas);`

I am just trying to narrow down where the problem is. There are two cases: `funcao2` is running and properly calling `novoBotao.addEventListener("click", modificar_horas);` so you can click the button. This would imply that the issue is somewhere in modificar_horas.

OR if the code inside of modificar_horas is not being executed at all, then the issue is in your interval somewhere.